# Customizing Login page moodle user type drop down

Tags: moodle

How can i add dropdown over login page?Although i am php developer but could not understand the feasible way.
i want to customize the the login page like  when user comes to login ,he should choose the type as has been registered there.

Suppose Taylor has been registered as trainer.When he come to login page and select the usertype as trainer then he should be logged in otherwise display some error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlcAV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a new field in the Moodle administration > Users > Profile fields form (`/user/profile/index.php`).

That being said, what is the purpose of a role control at login ? Your image looks like roles you can create and manage inside Moodle.

I mean, if a user logs in and happens to have the **engineer** platform role, Moodle handles the permissions internally (course access, course editing permissions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alternate login page with the `alternateloginurl` setting.

This will allow you to build your own page, just keep in mind:

> The page should contain a form which has the action property set to
>   '{your moodle site}/login/index.php' and return fields username
>   and password.

You can read documentation about this setting [here](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Managing_authentication#Alternate_login_URL)